# Why Kafka consumer performance is slow?

Tags: java, network-programming, bigdata, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka

I have one simple topic, and one simple Kafka consumer and producer, using the default configuration.

The program is very simple, I have two threads.

In the producer, it keeps sending 16 bytes data.

And in consumer side, it keeps receiving.

I found the fact that, the throughput for producer is roughly 10MB/s, that is fine.

But the throughput for consumer is only 0.2MB/s. I have disabled all the debugging logs but that does not make it any better. The test is running on local machine. Any body has an idea on what is going wrong? Thanks!

The code I used is below:
Producer:

```
KafkaProducer producer = new KafkaProducer(props);
int size = 16;
byte[] payload = new byte[size];
String key = "key";
Arrays.fill(payload, (byte) 1);
ProducerRecord record = new ProducerRecord("test",0,key.getBytes(),payload);
while(true){
producer.send(record);
}
```

Consumer:

```
Properties consumerProps = new Properties();
consumerProps.put("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181");
consumerProps.put("group.id", "test");
ConsumerConnector consumer = Consumer.createJavaConsumerConnector(new ConsumerConfig(consumerProps));
Map<String, Integer> topicCountMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
topicCountMap.put("test", 1);
Map<String, List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>>> consumerMap = consumer.createMessageStreams(topicCountMap);
List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>> streams = consumerMap.get("test");
ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> it = streams.get(0).iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
    it.next().message();
}
```

Comment: I have run the perf-consumer test for testing, it gives fair result of about 30MB/s, but still 0.2MB/s in my case.

Comment: Can you provide the link to the sample/example you followed.

Comment: did you solve the issue in the end?  I have a similar issue (using a .NET consumer) and find that refreshing metadata on calling consume takes approx 1s...

Comment: any update on this...similar issue on my end...

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring Consumers with the following properties.

1. `fetch.min.bytes`
2. `fetch.max.wait.ms`
3. `max.partition.fetch.bytes`

Also, you can adjust a timeout parameter of the `poll()` method for throughput.

```
ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
```