# Performance issue on kafka-net Consumer

Tags: .net, performance, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Using the kafka-net .NET consumer API, I have run into a performance problem (similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30959538/why-kafka-consumer-performance-is-slow) on the Java API) and cannot see how I have misconfigured the Consumer.  I am using the Wurstmeister Kafka Docker container, unmodified on OSX using docker-machine/virtualbox.  Sending messages takes approx 1ms. Consumption takes approx 950ms:

```
10:58:47,495 DEBUG [Threadpool worker] Kafka Utils [(null)]- >>>>: consuming
10:58:47,498 DEBUG [Threadpool worker] Kafka-net [(null)]- BrokerRouter: Refreshing metadata for topics: microservice.rapids
10:58:47,929 DEBUG [Threadpool worker] Kafka-net [(null)]- Received message of size: 89 From: http://192.168.99.100:9092/
10:58:48,432 DEBUG [Threadpool worker] Kafka-net [(null)]- Awaiting message from: http://192.168.99.100:9092/
10:58:48,436 DEBUG [Threadpool worker] Kafka-net [(null)]- Found address 192.168.99.100 for 192.168.99.100
10:58:48,436 DEBUG [Threadpool worker] Kafka-net [(null)]- Using address 192.168.99.100 for 192.168.99.100
10:58:48,445 DEBUG [Threadpool worker] Kafka Utils [(null)]- <<<<: consuming (950)ms
```

Here's how I constructed the Consumer.

```
Uri[] urls;
urls = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings ["kafka-urls"]
  .Split (',').Select (s => new Uri (s.Trim ())).ToArray ();
KafkaOptions options = new KafkaOptions (urls);
BrokerRouter router = new BrokerRouter (options);
return new Consumer (new ConsumerOptions (topic, router));
```

Which is as vanilla as I can make it.

500ms appeared to be spent refreshing metadata.  Is this something I can initiate up-front during construction of the BrokerRouter, so that it is not done during the consumption process?

Any other ideas why this would take so long, or how to avoid the delay?

Comment: I recently had some problems, and managed resolve them by making sure my URIs that I connected to specified the protocal and IP address instead of host name like this:  new Uri("tcp://" + ipAddressString + ":" + port)

Using http as the protocol never worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit from Broker Router and change GetCachedRoute .

I think what you trying to solve is very specific to you.
in case the leader is not the broker you expect it will be even longer.
Try to use PartitionWhitelist or MaxWaitTimeForMinimumBytes it can make the consume operation faster.

> it can fetch metadata once when it is instantiated cache that metadata until it receives an error indicating that the metadata is out of date. This error can come in two forms: (1) a socket error indicating the client cannot communicate with a particular broker, (2) an error code in the response to a request indicating that this broker no longer hosts the partition for which data was requested.

Comment: This sounds a bit more like a comment to me. Perhaps you can clarify.